# PHP, Mysql site wont load

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, while-loop

today i tesed make table from my database but somehow when i run tis code it load site forever =\ `$pismenka[0] to [25] are A, B, C .....`

Databse 100% works when i call it on single latter it works but when i use array it not =\

Echo is just for testing to see if data was found and if code reach to the end

PROBLEM SHORT : Site never loads so no ERRORS =\ just whitesmoke screen

PROBLEM PART :

`while($db_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect_to_db, "SELECT * FROM anime WHERE a_name LIKE '$start1%'"))) {
                    echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
                }`

WHOLE CODE :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pismenka); $i++) {
        echo "<div id='pismenko' class='text-center'>$pismenka[$i]</div>";
        $start1 = $pismenka[$i];
            echo "
            <table class=\"table table-striped table-hover\">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style=\"width: 30%;\">Názov anime</th>
                        <th style=\"width: 10%;\">Rok vydania</th>
                        <th style=\"width: 10%;\">Preložené</th>
                        <th style=\"width: 10%;\">Hodnotenie</th>
                        <th style=\"width: 10%;\">Preklad</th>
                        <th style=\"width: 10%;\">Stav</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
            ";
            while($db_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect_to_db, "SELECT * FROM anime WHERE a_name LIKE '$start1%'"))) {
                echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";

    }
```

Comment: @clearshot66 Nothing just LOADING, page LOAD forever when i press CTRL U i cant cause nothing was loaded

Comment: You've made an infinite `while` loop.  You keep re-executing the same query and getting the same results indefinitely.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Goose its 26 from A to Z

Comment: @David its not infinity loop i just load data to assoc array then call echo and loop ends when it runs out of DATA from database

Comment: And you've confirmed that this works when you load the page?  If it's working then what's the problem?

Comment: @David problem solved it was infinity loop cause i need store result and then give result to while loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because you keep re-executing the same query and getting the same results.

Execute the query *once*:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, "SELECT * FROM anime WHERE a_name LIKE '$start1%'");
```

Then loop over the *result* of that query:

```
while($db_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
}
```